# Сломалась android студио. Просит какой то репозиторий

Tags: android-studio

Просит какой то репозиторий, но если нажимаю установить - ошибка какая то. Студию я уже скачал новую и переустановил. и снова эта ошибка... что делать??

[image: Первый]
[image: Второй скрин]

Comment: Пробовали выключить и включить? :D

Comment: Попробуйте запустить Android Studio с правами администратора и повторить попытку. Она не может читать\писать в установочную папку.

Comment: Спасиб! ПОмогло! ТОлько от админа запускаю мои настройки темной темы куда то пропали, все белое аж глаза режет

Comment: Для разных пользователей свои настройки. Я добавлю ответ, примите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Следует запустить Android Studio с правами администратора и повторить попытку. Она не может читать\писать в установочную папку, у Windows'a с этим проблемы из "коробки", если Вы предварительно не меняли права доступа.

Comment: Кстати помогло, но я помню что раньше все работало и так, под обычным юзером. и самое интересно, я же эту студию юзал исключительно для phonegap - который сейчас перестал работать... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/708993/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F-phonegap-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9